# How to Remove Styles which by default apply in ASP.net Validation Controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Guys I am trying to remove default applied styles to the Validation Controls in asp.net. I am used Theam and set it Web.config still it applying.

How can i FIx

Comment: You need to see what css classes are being applied to the validation messages and modify those classes as per your need or override them in your own css file and use that css in the page.

Answer (score 1):

Create a CSS File and try to override this class `validator`,

```
.validator
{
    //add your CSS here and then use !important, for example: 
    color: black !important;
}
```

Then add this class to the Validation Control using CssClass property.

be sure to reference the CSS file to your layout or view or use `<Style>` tag at head and add this class.

Comment: Validation Control do not have a class assigned to them. This would work however if you add a `CssClass` to the Validator and give them that class name.